# How to print HTML source code TWIG view's

Tags: html, symfony, twig

In my project I have to **display a piece of the HTML source code of a TWIG view**. (What I can see with the keyshort `'Ctrl' + 'U'`)

And this piece of source code must **displaying in a other TWIG view** (so from an other Controller Action).
I'm working with Symfony2, is it possible and if yes how can I do that ?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to render the output html code from a controller in a different template?

If so, you could use the render function with the escape filter.

```
{{ render(
       controller(
           'AcmeBlogBundle:Comment:getComment', {'id': comment.id }
       )
   )|escape }} // or |e
```

This will render the controller response into an escaped string so all of the code will be visible to the end user.

Comment: AWESOME!!!! It's exactly what I wanted! It's perfectly displaying the HTML code source of my view! Thank you @Qoop ! :)